# Groovy Task in Ant Script to Customize Cobertura?

Tags: ant, groovy, cobertura

I am trying to customize the behavior of Cobertura for code coverage.. By default Cobertura instruments all the classes in the build but I want to read a particular xml which typically looks like :

```
<include>
    ....
    <targetclass name = "com.example.ExMain">
        <method name = "helloWorld" returnType="String">
    </target> 
    ....
</include>
```

I want to read such an xml that is supplied from an external source and customize Cobertura to instrument only the classes specified in the above xml.. For this I've written a groovy script and now I need to hook in the groovy script into the ant build script for Cobertura..

This is the portion of the ant section where the Cobertura actually instruments the classes.

```
...
<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
  <ignore regex="org.apache.log4j.*" />
  <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
   <exclude name="**/*.class" />//Custom change                                 
  </fileset>            
</cobertura-instrument>
...
```

Note that in the above section, I've explicitly excluded instrumentation of Cobertura to be able to hook in my script..

Apparently fileset doesn't allow me to include a groovy task inside it to invoke my custom script to read the xml.. If I place the groovy task outside, somehow the reports don't get generated.. So I guess there is no other option except for to invoke the groovy script within the fileset to include custom classes mentioned in the xml.. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set one or more properties in a separate Groovy block and reference them in your cobertura configuration. This simplified example shows how you can set an Ant property from your Groovy code snippet.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
<description>
    simple example build file
</description>

<path id="groovyPath">
    <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="groovy"
         classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"
         classpathref="groovyPath"/>
<target name="loadXml">
    <groovy>
        properties.parsedXml = 'some pattern that can be used to configure a task'
    </groovy>
</target>

<target name="configureTask" depends="loadXml">
    <echo message="${parsedXml}"/>
</target>
```